# Aligning items in table cells

Tags: tables

I have a table where I want more than one row in some cells. I am using parbox to achieve this but this makes some items in cells left aligned and some not. How can you fix this to make them all aligned the same way?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}   
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test page}   
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|}

   \hline
               \multirow{3}{*}  & Column one & Column two  \\
   \hline
   \hline
        Row one&  \textcolor{gray}{$f(n) = n^2$}  & \parbox{5cm}{$f(n) = n^2$ \\ $f(n) = n^2$}\\
        Row two &  \parbox{7cm}{\textcolor{gray}{$g(n,S) = n\sqrt{\log (n/S)/\log\log(n/S)})$} \\$g(n) = n^3$ } & $g(n) = n^3$\\
        Row three & \textcolor{gray}{$f(n) = n^2$} & \parbox{5cm}{$f(n) = n^2$\\ $f(n) = n^2$}\\
   \hline
   \end{tabular}%
}   
\end{frame}    
\end{document}
```

**Update.** Following the advice in the comments I have changed the table a little to show another problem.

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|}   
   \hline
               \multirow{3}{*}  & Column one & Column two  \\
   \hline
   \hline
        Row one&  \textcolor{gray}{$g(n,S) = n\sqrt{\log (n/S)/\log\log(n/S)})$}  & \parbox{5cm}{\centering $f(n) = n^2$ \\ $f(n) = n^2$}\\
        Row two &  \parbox{7cm}{\textcolor{gray}{\centering $g(n,S) = n\sqrt{\log (n/S)/\log\log(n/S)})$} \\ \centering $g(n) = n^3$ } & $g(n) = n^3$\\
        Row three & \textcolor{gray}{$f(n) = n^2$} & \parbox{5cm}{\centering $f(n) = n^2$\\ $f(n) = n^2$}\\
   \hline
   \end{tabular}%
}
```

g(n,S) is still not quite aligned the same in the first and second rows of "Column one".

Comment: You can use `\centering` inside a `\parbox` → `\parbox{5cm}{\centering $f(n) = n^2$ \\ $f(n) = n^2$}`

Comment: Also, why `\multirow{2}{*}`?

Comment: @HarishKumar I fixed the number of rows in \multirow, assuming I understand the syntax.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks. The trick for row two is to do  `Row two & \parbox{7cm}{\textcolor{gray}{ $g(n,S) = n\sqrt{\log (n/S)/\log\log(n/S)})$} \\ \centering$g(n) = n^3$ } & $g(n) = n^3$\` . That is the centering goes in the second row of the cell, not the first. I updated the question to show another problem however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use `\multirow{}` instead of `\parbox{}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test page}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|}
        \hline
            & Column one & Column two\\
        \hline
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{Row one} & \multirow{2}{*}{$g(n,S) = n\sqrt{\log (n/S)/\log\log(n/S)})$} & $f(n) = n^2$ \\
                & & $f(n) = n^2$ \\
        \multirow{2}{*}{Row two} & $g(n,S) = n\sqrt{\log (n/S)/\log\log(n/S)})$ & \multirow{2}{*}{$g(n) = n^3$} \\
            & $g(n) = n^3$ & \\
        \multirow{2}{*}{Row three} & \multirow{2}{*}{$f(n) = n^2$} & $f(n) = n^2$\\
            & & $f(n) = n^2$ \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}%
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using  `parbox`es that are bit narrower than your current settings. Thaat way, you won't have to use `\resizebox` to reduce the table's size, arguably making for a more-readable beamer page.

The code below also doesn't employ `\multirow` as I couldn't see a use for it. I do insert a couple of `\\[2ex]` spacing instructions to get more vertical separation between the three main rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test page}
\begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|}
   \hline
   & Column one & Column two  \\
   \hline
   \hline
        Row one&  
        \textcolor{gray}{$g(n,S) = n\sqrt{\log (n/S)/\log\log(n/S)}$}  & 
        \parbox{2cm}{\centering $f(n) = n^2$ \\ $f(n) = n^2$}\\[2ex]
        Row two &  \parbox{6cm}{\textcolor{gray}{
           \centering $g(n,S) = n\sqrt{\log (n/S)/\log\log(n/S)}$} \\ 
           \centering $g(n) = n^3$ } 
        & $g(n) = n^3$\\[2ex]
        Row three & \textcolor{gray}{$f(n) = n^2$} & 
        \parbox{1.75cm}{\centering $f(n) = n^2$\\ $f(n) = n^2$}\\
   \hline
   \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```