# Table cell vertical line missing

Tags: tables, multirow

The vertical line at the end of the cell where i used cell merge is missing.

[image]

Comment: Using `\multicolumn{3}{c|}{...}` should restore that puppy... Note that `\multicolumn` takes 3 arguments. :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please don't use screenshots for code- we need to be able to copy & paste it in order to work with it :)

Comment: Something is wrong with your use of `multirow`, you should use the `\multirow{}{}{}` command if you want to have that content in multiple rows (not the other way). Check [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140067/aligning-items-in-table-cells/140073#140073).

Comment: @Werner: the arguments are fine, the third parameter will be the entire cell but not more. A bit risky sometimes but it should work.

Answer (score 3):

That's not the only problem with your example.

Please note the following examples:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

multirow and multicolumn without brackets (brackets doesn't change much in this case, but they should be there)

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline  & \multicolumn{2}{c}.\\
\hline A & B & C \\
\hline D & \multirow{2}{*}E & F \\
\hline & G &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

... border added

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{.}\\
\hline A & B & C \\
\hline D & \multirow{2}{*}{E} & F \\
\hline & G &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

multiple borders added (no effect if matching)

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline  & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{.}\\
\hline A & B & C \\
\hline D & \multirow{2}{*}{E} & F \\
\hline & G &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

multiple borders added (affected if not matching)

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline  & \multicolumn{2}{||c|}{.}\\
\hline A & B & C \\
\hline D & \multirow{2}{*}{E} & F \\
\hline & G &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

multirow changed

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{.}\\
\hline A & B & C \\
\hline \multirow{2}{*}{D} & E & \multirow{2}{*}{F} \\
\hline & G &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

line fixed

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{.}\\
\hline A & B & C \\
\hline \multirow{2}{*}{D} & E & \multirow{2}{*}{F} \\
\cline{2-2} & G &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

alignm to top

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{.}\\
\hline A & B & C \\
\hline D & E & F \\
\cline{2-2}
 & G &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```