# multirow and multicolumn

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I want to draw a table which has multi-column in one row, as it is shown by the uploaded image. I have the code of a regular table in this style and I tried to modify it but failed. The uploaded image is a snapshot of word version table. I also want to control the line width between rows and columns, for the line width in LaTex is a little wider. So, it is not that pretty. BTW, is it possible to control the font of text in table?  Could you help a little? Appreciate that.

[image]

```
\definecolor{c1}{rgb}{0.30980, 0.50588, 0.73725}
\definecolor{c2}{rgb}{0.82353, 0.87843, 0.92941}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\color{c1}
\arrayrulecolor{white}  

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|l|}

\rowcolor{c2}
\multirow{3}{*}{Measure} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Description} & \multirow{3}{*}{NO.} \\
\hline

\rowcolor{c2}
{DFDF} & {fdsafdas} & {asdfasdf} & {asdfasd} \\
\hline

\rowcolor{c2}
{DFDF} & {fdsafdas} & {asdfasdf}  \\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: I can't find a `multirow` on the image. Does [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140346/36821) help?

Comment: Yes, really appreciate you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As masu mentioned, in showed picture you haven't multirows. probably with multirow you think on more lines in one cells, as you can see from example below:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{c1}{rgb}{0.30980, 0.50588, 0.73725}
\definecolor{c2}{rgb}{0.82353, 0.87843, 0.92941}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\arrayrulecolor{white}

    \begin{tabular}{|p{4em}|c|c|l|}
\rowcolor{c1}
\textcolor{white}{Measure} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textcolor{white}{Description}} 
                                        &   \textcolor{white}{NO.}  \\
    \hline
\rowcolor{c2}
DFDF    &   fdsafdas    &   asdfasdf    & {asdfasd}                 \\
    \hline
\rowcolor{c2}
DFDF DFDF   & fdsafdas  &   asdfasdf    &                           \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

May be like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,multirow}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{c1}{rgb}{0.30980, 0.50588, 0.73725}
\definecolor{c2}{rgb}{0.82353, 0.87843, 0.92941}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
%% \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3} %% can use this also
\color{c1}
\arrayrulecolor{white}

\begin{tabular}{|>{\rule{0pt}{2\baselineskip}}p{1.5cm}|
    >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}|
    >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5cm}|
    p{1.5cm}|}

\rowcolor{blue}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textcolor{white}{Measure}} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textcolor{white}{Description}} & \textcolor{white}{NO.} \\
\hline

\rowcolor{c2}
DFDF & fdsafdas & asdfasdf & asdfasd \\[\baselineskip]
\hline

\rowcolor{c2}
DFDF & \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth+8cm\relax}|}{fdsafdas  asdfasdf this line is going to be long and occypy the second line possibly} & asdfasdf \\[2\baselineskip]
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I have a regular table like below. How can I set the line width? I tried to use 'p{4em}', but I must used it incorrectly.

\definecolor{c1}{rgb}{0.30980, 0.50588, 0.73725}
\definecolor{c2}{rgb}{0.82353, 0.87843, 0.92941}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\color{c1}
\arrayrulecolor{white}  

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|}  % l or c means concentrate on the left side or center.
\hline
\rowcolor{c1}
\color{c2}Feature &
\color{c2}Format &
\color{c2}NO.\\hline

\rowcolor{c2}
LP1 & 256-histogram vector  & 1-C1 \\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}