# Borders are missing when using multicolumn

Tags: tables

I want to span a cell across two rows using multicolumn. This works but the borders are missing then.

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Multi-column}\\
    X&X\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Why does multicolumn omit the borders and how do I get the borders?

Comment: ...it's because you're *overriding* the column specification of the main `tabular` - `|c|c|` - with that of `\multicolumn` - `c`. The latter doesn't have any vertical rules in it. You should try `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{..}`.

Comment: We've had similar questions here before, so this is surely a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Table cell vertical line missing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140330/5764) (I couldn't find any better ones...)